# Ubuntu 23 Jupyter Notebook not recognizing Modules installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter

Being unable to use the normal pip install in Lunar Lobster, I installed the python packages through the apt install.... however jupyter does not recognize any packages on the system. Installing them in jupyter notebook is not working, I use pipx and it says it installed, however it will not import. Has anyone else run into this problem? I checked `sys.path`in jupyter and it returned

```
/home/arana
/usr/lib/python311.zip
/usr/lib/python3.11
/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload

/home/arana/.local/pipx/venvs/jupyter/lib/python3.11/site-packages
/home/arana/.local/pipx/shared/lib/python3.11/site-packages
```

[Jupyter Notebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wvxI.png)

Comment: Your screenshot says numpy is installed in `/home/arana/.local/pipx/venvs/numpy` but your `sys.path` does not include it. If you are using some other venv (likely `jupyter` - you will need to install it in there, maybe? Not sure how pipx works, but try `%pip install numpy` from within the notebook.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid now. I was trying to use `!pip install` instead of `%pip install`  Thank you so much! Working now!